# What is an efficient means to serve a dynamic website globally, in terms of latency?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, latency, percona-xtradb-cluster

We're using Amazon's AWS infrastructure. At one time, we did have a load-balanced setup across geographic regions, and our database cluster was divided between those regions. To reduce costs for the time being, and to solve some clustering issues we were having, we cut back to using regions inside the US only. Our latency in other regions is now totally horrible.

Using a CDN for assets (images, files) will satisfy our file-serving needs, but our site is extremely dynamic in nature with pages saving data frequently. This is definitely a First World Problem and one that's come about since the advent of AJAX. Surely, we do not need to re-invent the wheel.

Is using other regions in AWS the only option, and will we have to suck up the less-than-desired database clustering issues? Or... is there a better way?

Also, if we went with distinct architecture in each region, i.e. different database, is there an efficient means to keep data in sync between separate clusters. We're using Percona, for the record.

Comment: Similar question: https://serverfault.com/questions/628230/solution-for-php-mysql-website-loading-fast-in-multiple-regions/628252#628252

Comment: Thanks. The first solution given is almost exactly the way we had things set up. It looks like we may just have to bite the bullet once again.